# Create a view error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database

Hello I am trying to create a view using the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CONCERT_EVENTS1 AS
SELECT CONCERT.CONCERT_ID, EVENT.EVENT_ID, CONCERT.NAME, EVENT.DATE1 , CONCERT.DURATION,
CONCERT.COST AS TO_CHAR(COST, 'L9,999.99')                
FROM EVENT
INNER JOIN CONCERT
ON CONCERT.CONCERT_ID = EVENT.CONCERT_ID;
```

Below is the error I'm receiving:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CONCERT_EVENTS1 AS
SELECT CONCERT.CONCERT_ID, EVENT.EVENT_ID, CONCERT.NAME, EVENT.DATE1 , CONCERT.DURATION,
CONCERT.COST AS TO_CHAR(COST, 'L9,999.99')       
FROM EVENT
INNER JOIN CONCERT
ON CONCERT.CONCERT_ID = EVENT.CONCERT_ID
Error at Command Line:2 Column:113
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

What is the problem with my SQL?

Comment: what are you trying to do here `CONCERT.COST AS TO_CHAR(COST, 'L9,999.99') ` ?

Answer (score 1):

The AS statement is incorrect.  AS is used in selects to rename a column.  So CONCERT.COST as CONCERT_COST would rename the column to CONCERT_COST in your view.  If you want to format the column, that goes to the left of the as:

```
TO_CHAR(CONCERT.COST, 'L9,999.99')  AS FORMATED_COST
```

if you still want to rename the column.

Comment: Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CONCERT_EVENTS1 AS
SELECT CONCERT.CONCERT_ID, EVENT.EVENT_ID, CONCERT.NAME, EVENT.DATE1 , CONCERT.DURATION, CONCERT.COST TO_CHAR(CONCERT.COST, 'L9,999.99') AS FORMATED_COST
FROM EVENT
INNER JOIN CONCERT
ON CONCERT.CONCERT_ID = EVENT.CONCERT_ID
Error at Command Line:2 Column:110
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Answer (score 0):

Your "AS TO_CHAR(COST, 'L9,999.99')" is not quite right.  The "As" statement is used to alias a column, you don't want the column to be named "TO_CHAR(COST, 'L9,999.99')"

I believe what you want is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CONCERT_EVENTS1 AS
SELECT CONCERT.CONCERT_ID, EVENT.EVENT_ID, CONCERT.NAME, EVENT.DATE1 , CONCERT.DURATION,
TO_CHAR(CONCERT.COST, 'L9,999.99') as 'ALIAS_HERE'
FROM EVENT
INNER JOIN CONCERT
ON CONCERT.CONCERT_ID = EVENT.CONCERT_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This message always indicates a syntax error in the query projection, the bit between the SELECT and the FROM keywords:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

You are still getting it because you have muffed the suggested fix for your original bloomer.  Now you have *two* declarations for the COST column ....

```
CONCERT.COST TO_CHAR(CONCERT.COST, 'L9,999.99') AS FORMATED_COST
```

Syntax demands we put a comma between every column in the projection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CONCERT_EVENTS1 AS 
    SELECT CONCERT.CONCERT_ID
            , EVENT.EVENT_ID
            , CONCERT.NAME
            , EVENT.DATE1 
            , CONCERT.DURATION
            , CONCERT.COST
            , TO_CHAR(CONCERT.COST, 'L9,999.99') AS FORMATED_COST 
FROM EVENT INNER 
      JOIN CONCERT 
         ON CONCERT.CONCERT_ID = EVENT.CONCERT_ID
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the numeric COST column in the view just drop it.

---

I know syntax errors are hard for beginners but you really need to learn to look at your own code with a cool eye.  You can't come running to SO every time you've dropped a comma.  Laying out your code in a proper fashion will help: code which is easier to read is easier to debug.  For the same reason you should avoid putting all your code in UPPER CASE.